# How to Run private class method.in same class

Tags: java, oop, private, program-entry-point

Can figure why it won't allow me to run the `displaymainMethod` because it's private even though I know I can run it from from same class. Is there a way to do this without using reflective API?

This is the error

```
Error:(10, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class displayMainMenu
  location: class LoginPrototype
```

Code

```
import java.util.*;

public class LoginPrototype {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Credentials> allUsers = new ArrayList<Credentials>();
        displayMainMenu mainMenu = new displayMenu();
    }

    private void displayMainMenu() {
        int input;
        do {
            System.out.println("Menu Options");
            System.out.println("[1] Login");
            System.out.println("[2] Register");
            System.out.println("[0] Quit");//5 Displaying Main Menu Options
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            input = sc.nextInt();

            if (input > 2) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a value of [0] - [2]");
            }
            else if (input == 1){
                System.out.println("Login");
            }
            else if (input == 2){
                System.out.println("Register");
            }
            else if (input == 0){
                System.out.println("Thank you. bye.");
            }
        }while(input >= 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the compiler error in your question.

Comment: if `displayMenu()` is a method, why the `new` keyword in front of it??? either make it a class, or make the method return the intance of the class you want; you can't do both in one call.

Comment: Also, you can't call nonstatic methods from main, even once you fix your creation syntax

Comment: Error:(10, 9) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class displayMainMenu
  location: class LoginPrototype

Comment: following the assignment instruction

Comment: thats the method creation we were asked to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems here.

The first problem is the scope of your call. In the `main` method, you're trying to make a call to a method that requires an object reference. Main is static, displayMainMenu isn't. So, in order to call it, you need to instantiate a reference of the encapsulating class.

The next problem is the method call. displayMainMenu() is a method, not a type. So the `new` keyword doesn't apply here.

The next problem is the method's return type. `displayMainMenu()` has a return type of void. Void can't be assigned to a variable.

Try to change it to:

```
import java.util.*;

public class LoginPrototype {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Credentials> allUsers = new ArrayList<Credentials>();
    LoginPrototype lp = new LoginPrototype();
    lp.displayMenu();
}

private void displayMainMenu() {
    //Do stuff
}
}
```

That solves the major problems with the code.

Comment: import java.util.*;


public class LoginPrototype {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LoginPrototype main = new LoginPrototype();
        main.displayMainMenu();

        ArrayList<Credentials> allUsers = new ArrayList<Credentials>();
    }


    private void register(){
        handleCredentialInput(ArrayList<>) = new Credentials();

    }
}

Comment: 'import java.util.*;


public class LoginPrototype {


    private void register(){
        handleCredentialInput(ArrayList<>) = new Credentials();

    }
}'

Answer (score 0):

```
 displayMainMenu mainMenu = new displayMenu();
```

This line does not make sense. You are treating the function like an object.
You should just call the function itself: `displayMainMenu();`

But make the function public.

Comment: @MrA What exactly you are not allowed to do? Change `displayMainMenu mainMenu = new displayMenu();` into `displayMainMenu();` or making `displayMainMenu` method `public`?

Comment: B.Milford and @MrA making this method public is not required, class can access any of its members, even private ones. Making it `static` makes more sense.